# SoF2 shell script not running

Tags: bash, shell

I've got the following code in my shell script:

```
SERVER=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c sof2ded`
    if ["$SERVER" != "0"]; then
        echo "Already Running, exiting"
        exit
    else
        echo "Starting up the server..."
        cd /home/sof2/
        /home/sof2/crons/start.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
```

I did `chmod a+x status.sh`

Now I try to run the script but it's returning this error:

```
./status.sh: line 5: [1: command not found
Starting up the server...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try changing a few things in your script as follows and let me know if that helps you?(changed back-tick to `$` and changed `[` to `[[` in code)

```
SERVER=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c sof2ded)
    if [[ "$SERVER" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Already Running, exiting"
        exit
    else
        echo "Starting up the server..."
        cd /home/sof2/
        /home/sof2/crons/start.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `test` command.   "But", I hear you say, "I am not using the `test` command".  Yes you are, it is also known as `[`.

`if` statement syntax is `if` *command*.  The brackets are not part of `if` syntax.

Commands have arguments separated (*tokenized*) by whitespace, so:

```
[ "$SERVER" != "0" ]
```

The whitespace is needed because the command is `[` and then there are 4 arguments passed to it (the last one must be `]`).

A more robust way of comparing numerics is to use double parentheses,

```
(( SERVER == 0 ))
```

Notice that you don't need the `$` or the quotes around `SERVER`.  Also the spacing is less important, but useful for readability.

`[[` is used for comparing text patterns.

As a comment, backticks `  ` are considered deprecated because they are difficult to read, they are replaced with `$( ... )`.